# Putting a prompt in shell (w/ cursor for input) *above* a list of options

Tags: linux, bash

So I want to know if it is possible to print something on a console *below* a prompt where user input is solicited.

```
read -p "Would you like to choose an apple or a pear? "
echo "5 apples"
echo "3 pears"
```

Something like this, where you prompt a user on a first line, but something is writen below it. Im not sure how I should solve this, because when I prompt the user, script execution waits for a response.

---

To be clear, my intent is a prompt that looks like the following, where the `_` represents cursor location:

```
Would you like to choose an apple or a pear? _
5 apples
3 pears
```

I was experimenting with a timer to write subsequent prompt lines in the background, but would prefer other angles of solving this if possible.

Comment: It is definitely possible, editors like emacs use it. As far as I know the library `ncurses` can handle this, but I've never used it myself

Answer (score 2):

*A quick note* -- If seeking compatibility with baseline POSIX shells or systems without `tput`, please see the [answer by @Attie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073725/14122) on this question. This answer has the advantage of working with non-ANSI terminals on account of its use of `tput`, but the other is compatible with a wider array of shells.

---

`tput` can be used to look up the appropriate control sequence to be used to move the cursor to a given location. In the below example, we're going to start with a cleared screen, so we know that the prompt will always be printed at the top-left corner -- `(0,0)`.

```
# start with an empty screen
clear

# print an empty line, then "5 apples" on the next line, and "3 pairs" on the third
printf '%s\n' '' "5 apples" "3 pairs"

# Move the cursor back to the top-left-corner
tput cup 0 0

# ...and print the prompt there.
read -p "Would you like to choose an apple or a pear? "
```

---

One can avoid the need to clear the screen first by using `tput cuu` to move the cursor up the desired number of lines, and `tput cud` to move it down:

```
# print an empty line, then "5 apples" on the next line, and "3 pairs" on the third
printf '%s\n' '' "5 apples" "3 pairs"

# Move the cursor up three lines...
tput cuu 3

# ...and print the prompt there.
read -p "Would you like to choose an apple or a pear? "

# finally, after input has been entered, move the cursor down three lines
tput cud 3
```

Comment: *print something on a console while waiting for user input* - your answer might be a workaround, but not a solution to the problem of the OP

Comment: I disagree. If you have a question and two answers below I as the user would like the cursor to be at the end of the question and not behind the last possible answer

Comment: Yes thats the problem, cursor should be on the first line, or I wouldnt be having this trouble. But I agree that would be for the best in all other cases :D

Comment: @msrd0, agreed, but the OP didn't **ask** that -- absolutely nothing in the question specifies cursor position. They should edit their question to be more specific. :)

Comment: Oh I thought the picture should demonstrate how it shouldn't look like ... and the op asked to print text on the next line without moving the cursor, which should be to print text and then move the cursor back to current position

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad. But you are right tput is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Command line interfaces will typically show the options first, and then ask the question second... often with the default response given. I would encourage you to do the same.

More typical output would be:

```
Options:
  1.  Apple   (5 available)
  2.  Pear    (3 available)
What would you like? [1] _
```

In this case the user can enter `1` for an Apple, `2` for a Pear, or nothing for the default (Apple, which is presented in square brackets).

*Note*: underscore is used to show the position of the cursor, as apparently that is part of the discussion.

---

It *is* possible to put your prompt above the options, but this will require you to position the cursor (not always supported), and may present some confusion to a new user. You might like to look into [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (or some abstraction thereof, e.g: `ncurses` / `tput`).

In the example below, the cursor movement should be tightly coupled with the input loop (thanks to @Charles for his input).

```sh
# reserve a line
echo ''

# present options
echo '5 apples'
echo '3 pears'

# move 'up' 2x lines (n-options)
printf '%b' '\e[2A'

# get input
while [ 1 ]; do
    # move the cursor to column 1
    # move 'up' 1x line, and
    # clear to the end of the line
    printf '%b' '\e[G\e[1A\e[K'

    # prompt for input
    printf '%s' 'Would you like to choose an apple or a pear? '
    read choice

    # validate input
    case $choice in
        apple | \
        pear  )
            break
            ;;
    esac
done

# move 'down' 2x lines (n-options)
printf '%b' '\e[2B'

# output user's input
echo "User picked ${choice}"
```

Comment: Minor little quibble to what's generally a good answer at this point -- `==` isn't guaranteed to work in `[` across shells; the POSIX-specified string comparison operator is `=`. One might also consider `case $choice in (apple|pear) break;; esac`. (That said, `read -p` is a bashism anyhow, so one might just switch from `[` to `[[` to make reliance of extensions in the test operations explicit).

Comment: More learning, thanks @Charles! Swapped `if` for `case`, and `read -p` for `echo -n; read`... hopefully my use of `case` isn't yet another bashism!

Comment: As far as I know (and as far as Shellcheck knows), the way you're using `case` here is perfectly portable. That said, you might consider `printf '%s' "..."` instead of `echo -n` -- while POSIX *allows* shells to implement `-n`, it doesn't *require* them to do so.

Comment: Looks good. This is now quite certainly the more portable answer of the two. :)

Comment: Righto... I thought you just implied that `echo -n` was okay? Or am I mis-remembering a deleted comment?

Comment: Sorry -- I tried to split a hair in that comment, and may have done so poorly. Basically, POSIX *allows* but doesn't require `-n`, whereas it *disallows* everything else (including `-e`). Incidentally, if bash has `xpg_echo` enabled it follows this spec when in POSIX mode, and will (only then) print `-e` on output when given `echo -e`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html if you'd care to read the spec yourself.

Comment: (BTW, I've amended my answer to point folks at this one if they need cross-OS compatibility more than cross-terminal compatibility. Thank you for putting up with all the nitpicking!)

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for nitpicking, always interested to learn!